# The number of characters in one line is very different from `window-width`

Tags: window, characters

In my environment, I can only enter 130 single-byte characters in one line in the actual buffer while `window-width` is returning 160. Apparently `window-width` is returning columns, not characters. Is there a way to convert columns to number of characters or to calculate the number using the columns and some attributes of current font?(for now, only the case of fixed-width one)

Actual reference values are:

`window-width`: 159

`window-total-width`: 160

`window-pixel-width`: 1602

`window-font-width`: 10

Comment: Show what the 130 characters are? Some chars are double-width etc.

Comment: Fixed the question. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`window-width` (which is an alias for `window-body-width`) has nothing to do with the buffer text.  It's not the length of the longest line, it's the width of the window (and in columns, as you surmised).

Furthermore:

> On a graphical display, the latter actually correspond to the height and
> width of a default character specified by the frame’s default font as
> returned by ‘frame-char-height’ and ‘frame-char-width’ (*note Frame
> Font::).  Thus, if a window is displaying text with a different font or
> size, the reported line height and column width for that window may
> differ from the actual number of text lines or columns displayed within
> it.

See <kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>i</kbd><kbd>g</kbd> `(elisp)Window Sizes`

Comment: Yes I know that, but I want to know how many letters can be stored in one line of current window(Is it possible to calculate using the columns and some attributes of current font?), regardless of what is entered currently in current-buffer.

Comment: How many of *which* letters?  Any given character may be a different width to any other character.

Comment: Maybe you want `window-font-width` ?

Comment: `window-font-width`: 10(shown in the question) might be used like `(/ (window-pixel-width) (window-font-width))` to calculate `window-width` internal? It seems that the number I want does not come out from this value.

Comment: With your accurate suggestions, I've come to feel like there is no such method because the calculation for the number of characters from `window-width` is nonsense in a world where there are variable-width fonts.